# Calling a void-parameter lambda gives compiler error

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

From this question: [Lambda expression with a void input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1509241/lambda-expression-with-a-void-input)

I have the following very simple code:

```
        int minutes = () => 9;
```

I get compiler error:

> Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'int' because it is not a
>   delegate type

I've found several questions about this error but they're all about more specific issues. I actually want to give my lambda a body but thought I'd start simple first to check my syntax:

```
//I know this is a weird example
int minutes = ()=> { if(x==9) return 9; else return 5;}
```

Comment: `() => 9` is a `Func<int>` or `Expression<Func<int>>` not an `int`.

Comment: @Lee is right, here's a fiddle

https://dotnetfiddle.net/K3MoCc

Comment: Well great now I know it's `Expression<Func<int>>` everything is clear ;) @SalvadorGuerrero thanks for that expansion... I have to assign my lambda to an explicitly typed variable? I cannot call it on the fly or assign to a plain old `var`?

Comment: Note that `Expression<Func<int>>` and `Func<int>` are quite different things and you probably want the latter here.

Comment: Also, technically you can do it on one line, but that would be madness - just write an `if` statement! For example, this works but the gods of programming will rain fire and brimstone down upon you if you use it: `int y = ((Func<int>)(() => 9))();`

Comment: It's ... well, lambda expression with no arguments returning `int`. Hence you cannot use `var` because it can be any compatible delegate/expression type.

Comment: The thing is - lambda can be compiled to different things.
You can see how c# compiler work under the hood here -> https://tryroslyn.azurewebsites.net/#f:r/K4Zwlgdg5gBAygTxAFwKYFsDcBYAUKSWRFDAOgBlIBHUgUQA8AHAJ1RHAHsIQdc9HgAIwA2YAMYwxwgIbsYAYRgBvPDDUwBI8TABuHMABMYAWQAUASmV4AkNYBiwCGIA8kZAD4Y6SMDQgYALwwFoGeAJy8tgwsbJwQzg5OrhAenvT0gcGWAeG86jAAvngFQA

Comment: @DavidG I'd say that's basically an answer...

Comment: @Mr.Boy To post that as an answer, I'd have to sacrifice a puppy to the gods of programming first. And I like puppies. If it was a kitten though...

Answer (score 0):

From [C# guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/articles/csharp/lambda-expressions)

> A lambda expression is a block of code (an expression or a statement block) that is treated as an object. It can be passed as an argument to methods, and it can also be returned by method calls.

...

> Lambda expressions are code that can be represented either as a delegate, or as an expression tree that compiles to a delegate.

That means lambda expression can be represented and can represent different things: delegate or expression tree.

Your expression

```
() => 9;
```

can be so many different things, as example

```
public class C {
delegate int IntDelegate();
public void M() {
    Func<int> minutes = () => 9;
    IntDelegate minutes2 = () => 9;
    Expression<Func<int>> minutesExpression = () => 9;
    Expression<IntDelegate> minutesExpression2 = () => 9;
}
}
```

So what do you want to use?

By the way, because of all that, you can't use var with them.
And you can see how c# compiler work under the hood for different lambda here-> [lambda as delegate and expression tree](https://tryroslyn.azurewebsites.net/#K4Zwlgdg5gBAygTxAFwKYFsDcBYAUKSWRFDAOgBlIBHUgUQA8AHAJ1RHAHsIQdc9HgAIwA2YAMYwxwgIbsYAYRgBvPDDUwAJqmGoo0tDEjIYASQjIAItt37UACgCUvdTAEjxMAG4cwGmAFlHZTwASBCAMWAIMQAeIwA+GHRIYDQQGABeGCCMxIBOXjCzS2s9A2SIVLYAJkzsh0z8wpCGFjZOCBjI6LjzeMSKqpBW1nYwLjqcptUXdRH28c7iqx0y1AGUtPmxrlqsqZgCmbUAXzwToA==)